# Build Failure Analyzer plugin for Jenkins: Match Text returns Invalid Url

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am working with the [Build Failure Analyzer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Failure+Analyzer) plugin for Jenkins. It works fine when I use `Plain Text` as the `Text Source`, but when I select `Build Log` I get an `Invalid Url` error after clicking `Match Text`.

The pattern I am using is :

```
.*no JMeter files matching .* for a Jmeter Project
```

And the text which I am matching is :

```
http://localhost:8080/job/Project%20Jmeter/4/
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove %20 in the URL and replace it with blankspace

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things that you have to check for this.  I'm leaving this for anyone else who might have ran into the same thing that I did.  First, you need to ensure that any %20 is a blankspace as previously mentioned, but another one that caught me up is that it is not the URL to the console logs, even through the drop down mentions build log.  You are providing a link to the build itself.

You do not seem to have this problem, but it has tripped me up multiple times.